# Probit ordered model for non-normal distribution of outcomes

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, probit

I have the following Y outcomes distribution with the normal density function represented by the superimposed red line:

[image]

I need to develop a regression methodology to predict $Y$ given a number of predictors $X_n$. OLS doesn't seem to fit the bill because of the non-normal distribution of $Y$.

Given that the outcomes are non-continuous increments of 0.5, would an ordered probit regression be the right approach? As I understand it, a probit regression allows to specify the distribution of the outcomes. What other alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Which distribution of the dependent variable is relevant?**

First, there is no reason to think that OLS will do badly on this data.  At least none from looking at your dependent variable.  However...

Second, Looking at the distribution of your dependent variable is not so helpful.  Even regression models that assume Normally distributed errors only expect them to be Normal after conditioning on X.  This does not imply that the marginal distribution is Normal, which is what you plot here, I think.  So seeing fat tails here is not *necessarily* a problem.

**Models and distributional assumptions**

OLS does not describe a model but a procedure (minimise the sum of squared errors).  OLS generated coefficient estimates have various properties depending on what you are happy to assume by way of an actual statistical model of the the data generating process.  The more you assume, the more you get to say.  Any good econometrics text will go into the gory details of this, since econometricians always want to know what they can infer from as few assumptions as possible.  But in short, you can go a long way without explicitly assuming they are even conditionally Normal.

**Probit regression and the alternatives**

Probit does allow you to specify a distribution.  Indeed, all generalised linear model, a class which includes homoskedastic linear models for which OLS is the maximum likelihood estimation procedure and probit models allow you to specify the distribution of the dependent variable.  You can always do that.  And you can often only partially specify it too and get some more general results.  The class of generalised linear models provides a good starting point when looking for 'alternatives'.

**The histogram**

I don't know if I understand the graph properly because I can't see anything that varies at 0.5 intervals (except the histogram bins, but they are *designed* to do that sort of thing).  So thus far, I see no reason to consider probit models.

Comment: The outcomes are discrete in 0.5 as I stated in the questions.

Comment: so how did you make the graph in the question?

Comment: The problem I have with a linear solution is relative to the kurtosis of the Y distribution, not the skewness. Isn't the normality of outcomes a requirement of OLS regression?

Comment: The graph is an histogram of the results I need to predict. I did use a continuous variable to produce the graph but ultimately I am only interested in the discretized version of the continuous variable.

Comment: re kurtosis: as I said in the answer under the usual Normality assumption, high kurtosis (a.k.a 'fat tails') in P(Y|X) matters and in P(Y) does not matter.  I didn't say anything about skew.

Comment: Thank you for following up with the details of my question. I should be more clear: what I really meant is that I am concerned about the "peakedness" of my outcome distribution, not the fat tails. I'm figuring that a linear predictor would tend to smooth results without accounting for the steep change in the outcome values starting at the +/-5 level to 0 (center of the distribution). For more details on where I am coming from check http://press.princeton.edu/books/lo/chapt10.pdf, Chapter 10.6.3.

Comment: 1. for fixed variance, fatter tail *implies* tighter peak - that's how kurtosis works
2. your link on p.288: "But discreteness is of paramount importance for intraday price movements, since such finely-sampled price changes may take on only *five or six distinct values*" (not what is in your graph)
3. Please read what I said about conditional and marginal distributions!

Comment: ok for 1 and 2. But I'd still like to point you to page 332 Fig. 10.5 where the OLS probability distribution is compared to the probit version and the prob distribution for CUE in particular. Why the probit dist differs so dramatically from the "more normal" OLS version? Isn't the nonlinear relationship better captured by the probit regression?

Comment: Not quite ok for 2. The 'non-linearities' in the predictive probabilities are due to having *unevenly spaced* cut points slicing the probit's (conditionally Normal) latent variable.  Some slices are just bigger than others.  The question for you is whether your data are genuinely ordinal (cut points could be very unevenly spread) or just coarsely measured (effective cut points are 0.5 intervals and do not need to be estimated).  In the latter case, treating the dv as continuous will be ok.  Re 3. the nonlinearity can be dealt with via probit *if you've got it*, but the graph leaves that open.

Comment: Thanks, indeed the distribution of the outcomes does not imply non-normality of the residuals. And yes, by rereading the article the tick cutoffs are not equally spaced.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but I just came across it. Just one quick comment - when your range is so large, 0.5 increments are fairly minute. That means it approaches being a continuous variable, and linear regression would be far easier to interpret than an ordered logit. Ordered logit coefficients are easy to look at, but not so a) simple to explain to a non-technical audience and b) not very detailed. They tell you the proportional odds above and below a line (odds ratio of moving up the chain, but don't know how far up you go).

As conjugateprior implied, I would use this histogram to say "Yeah, this looks close enough to normal to me let's model with OLS or GLS or something linear", and then look at the residuals you get. In my experience normality tests are very sensitive, so if you have high kurtosis like this in the residuals, it may not be the end of the world for you. Social scientists eyeball these things all the time, it's kind of common procedure (for better or worse).